# net core 2.2 local customized user account System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

I created project in net core 2.2 with local user account and added all identity files using scaffolding. I created in my model folder two files `ApplicationUser.cs` and `ApplicationRole.cs`. Then I modified `startup.cs` and `applicationdbcontext` to use new attributes for user and role. Now I have to change all relations from `IdentityUser` to `ApplicationUser` in all classes in `Areas/Identity`. Am I missing something or this is expected behavior?

I get the error before changing relation from `IdentityUser` to `ApplicationUser`.

Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LogoutModel'.
    private readonly SignInManager _signInManager;

to

```
private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
 }
```

startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
```

I want to be sure that I didn't miss something or made a mistake.

Comment: In your controller or the view UserManager<IdentityUser> change to UserManager<ApplicationUser>

Comment: I knew that and I did. It works but I have to do the change in every file/class in Identity area. I'm looking for complex solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you have shown, the main problem that stands out to me is that you never assign anything to `_signInManager`.

```
class Foo // your class
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

    public Foo() // your constructor
    {
        _signInManager = ; //<-- this
    }
}
```

Which at this point, shows that it is defined as `null`.

Comment: I know that. I have to do the change in every file/class in Identity area. I'm looking for complex solution.